# Spark DataFrame from a Sparse data

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have sparse data which I want to import to a `DataFrame` in `Spark`. For e.g. my data may look like

```
 val point1 = ("name": "Alice", "age": 20)
 val point2 = ("name": "Bob", "weight": 150.4)
```

Note, the sparseness in the representation: field `age` appears only in `point1`, while `weight` only in `point2` etc.

What is the easiest way to import this data as a `DataFrame` in Spark? I don't want to go the `SparseVector` -> `RDD[LabeledPoint]` -> `DataFrame` way, for it requires one extra pass through the whole data for creating a Vector.

Comment: Do you know all features by compile time? Then it should be possible to pass them so you don't need the extra pass over the data. Otherwise I don't see a way around.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I want to run on different experiments with different constraints, objective etc. And then there are some categorical features with varying ranges as well :(.